# MVC4 and SignalR Real Time DB Notification breaking because of the jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, push-notification, signalr

Net MVC4 Real Time DB Notification using signal R. I did all possible approaches to get my application out. but i am stuck in the JQuery error.

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'client'
>   of undefined or null reference

I did all possible suggestions.

I will List out my points here with code:

1. I am using MVC4 and SignalR version 2.1.2
2. Jquery Version is 1.10.2
3. I am using razor view engine
4. I am following an article where i will fetch my DB Records using Partial views.

MyHub looks like this

```
public class MessagesHub : Hub
{

    public static void SendMessages()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessagesHub>();
        context.Clients.All.updateMessages();
    }

}
```

MyView Look Like this

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

}



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="messagesTable">

            @ViewBag.Message="Div to include messages";
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>

<script src="~/Hubs/signalr/hubs"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {


         var notifications = $.connection.messagesHub;

            //debugger;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            notifications.client.updateMessages = function () {
                getAllMessages()
            };
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                alert("connection started")
                getAllMessages();
            }).fail(function (e) {
                alert(e);
            });
        });
        function getAllMessages() {
            var tbl = $('#messagesTable');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/home/GetMessages',
                contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html'
            }).success(function (result) {
                tbl.empty().append(result);
            }).error(function () {
            });
        }
    </script>


    }
```

Soon as it reaches View page, it throwing an error. i changed my hub path giving tilde and all. but still am unable to get this out. help me out please.

***Error*** is killing me.

Comment: problem is here:``notifications.client.updatemessages`` , notification is undefined so when you access ``client`` property it throws error

Comment: Is **Hubs** folder in root directory of project?

Answer (score 0):

I Updated my jquery to 1.10.2 and removed my HUB reference  and it worked, i really dont know what was the issue. its kinda of fluke. but worked how ever. thanks @Ehsan for your valuable comment.

Comment: this in actually invalid:``<script src="~/Hubs/signalr/hubs"></script>`` , in src we have to give js file reference and your's is not right

Comment: Yes, i mentioned in my comment. i removed and added properly, but i was stuck due to the invariable version of signalR and Jquery. made my scripts render as false in my _layout page, before it was true.